# What is assembly and what is the use of it?

Tags: .net

Im beginner for asp.net Could you tell me what is assembly? and what is the use of it?
if i have the questions regarding assemblies how to make answer? please help me.

Answer (score 3):

An assembly is a compilation unit in .NET, it is either a DLL or an EXE file.

`What is the use of it?`

From the wikipedia page about [.NET assemblies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_assembly):

> In the Microsoft .NET framework, an assembly is a partially compiled  code library for use in deployment, versioning and security.

Comment: although you are right in most cases, but don't forget about modules.

Answer (score 2):

Assembly is the general concept in .net, not specific to asp.net. Full answer is that assembly is minimal addressable container of types. in 99% cases assembly is just dll/exe with your classes.